# How to parse JSON Object Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, api

The JSON Object

```
{"Title":"Batman Returns","Year":"1992","Rated":"PG-13","Released":"19 Jun 1992","Runtime":"126 min","Genre":"Action","Director":"Tim Burton","Writer":"Bob Kane (Batman characters), Daniel Waters (story), Sam Hamm (story), Daniel Waters (screenplay)","Actors":"Michael Keaton, Danny DeVito, Michelle Pfeiffer, Christopher Walken","Language":"English","Country":"USA, UK","Awards":"Nominated for 2 Oscars. Another 2 wins & 15 nominations.","Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODM2OTc0Njg2OF5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwMDA4NjQxMTE@._V1_SX300.jpg","Metascore":"N/A","imdbRating":"7.0","imdbVotes":"199,878","imdbID":"tt0103776","Type":"movie","Response":"True"}
```

I'm trying to parse this object in android studio however im getting an error:

```
of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

This is the code that I'm using

```
JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResult);
JSONObject movieObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);

String title = movieObject.getString("Title");
```

Comment: Very clear from log :`JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray` means need to change `JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResult);` to `JSONObject mJsonArray = new JSONObject(jsonResult);`

Comment: and to get values using keys do it as : `String title = mJsonArray.getString("Title");` and remove `JSONObject movieObject = mJsonArray.getJSONObject(0);` line completely

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your json contains an object, not an array. Replace

```
JSONArray mJsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonResult);
```

by

```
JSONObject movieObject = new JSONObject(jsonResult);    
String title = movieObject.getString("Title");
```