# Get string from jsonArray java android

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, object

I am making an android app and have to use json. I am very new to JSON so I have a question. I have got the following json code from a HttpUrlConnection:

```
 [{"id":"12","name":"John","surname":"Doe","age":"23","username":"123"}]
```

How can I convert this string to a jsonArray and get the "23" out of this array using java? I already searched a lot on stackoverflow but didn't got the right answer. Hope somebody could help me.

I already tried to make it an jsonObject but it didn't work. Result is the string I've got from the HttpUrlConnection:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
String jsonname = jsonObject.getString("age");
```

Comment: Which JSON library are you using?

Comment: I am using android studio. I thought Json was already build in android studio

Comment: What's the fully qualified name of the JsonObject class, just to be sure which one you're using?

Comment: I suspect you'll need to instantiate a JsonArray, rather than a JsonObject. The string above is an array, which you should then be able to interrogate for its individual items.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The JSON string you've supplied is an array (containing a single element). Try using this instead:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(result);

// This gets you the first (zero indexed) element of the above array.
JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
String age = jsonObject.getString("age");
```

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742944/how-to-parse-json-object-android-studio) question, but you have the opposite problem.