# Get information from an ObjectJson without Array

Tags: android, json

I have the class below and I can fetch information from a JSONArray in this format:

**{"cliente":[{"id":"1334","nome":"Bruno"}]}**

```
TextView nome_usuario;

private static final String TAG_CLIENTE = "cliente";
private static final String TAG_NOME = "nome";

JSONArray cliente = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View grafico = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment_perfil, container, false);
nome_usuario = (TextView ) grafico.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
new JSONParse().execute();
return grafico;
}


private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {
private ProgressDialog pDialog;
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
    pDialog.setMessage("Atualizando");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();

}

@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl("url do json");
        return json;

}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    try {
        cliente = json.getJSONArray(TAG_CLIENTE);
        JSONObject c = cliente.getJSONObject(0);
        String nome = c.getString(TAG_NOME);
        nome_usuario.setText(nome);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
}

}
```

But now I would like to work with a json in the following format:

**{"name": "Bruno"}**

I found a question similar to my [How to parse JSON Object Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742944/how-to-parse-json-object-android-studio), but I could not apply it to my example.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to find information in the second json, due to the fact that it does not have array only with NULL as an answer

Comment: Which information you want to take? Value of key `name`is that you need?

Comment: Yes, I would like to access it

Answer (score 0):

**Getting information from an JSONObject:**

```
JSONObject aJsonObject = new JSONObject(aJsonResponse);
JSONArray aJsonArray = aJsonObject.getJSONArray("cliente");
for (int i = 0; i < aJsonArray.length(); i++) {
    aJsonObject = aJsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
String aId = aJsonObject .getString("id");
String aNome = aJsonObject .getString("nome");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this, you should replace aJsonResponse with the response from the server

```
JSONObject aJsonObject = new JSONObject(aJsonResponse);

String aId = aJsonObject.getString("id");
String aNome = aJsonObject.getString("name");
```