# Parsing Json object received from rest api

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am using `Volley` library to execute my rest APIs.

Using this I have sent email, password entries to URL and receiving response in JSON as:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
        "message": false,
        "token": "some token value"
    }
}
```

Now I want to parse the 'token' field received from response and do further action. How can this be parsed?

This is the function where I want to parse the response.

```
public void parseData(String response) {

try {
     JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
     if (jsonObject.getString("success").equals("true")) {

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"UserExists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

           ////RETRIEVE "token" HERE

        else {

         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"User not registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
```

I have seen this link [How to parse JSON Object Android Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33742944/how-to-parse-json-object-android-studio) but my "token" field is within another object, so not sure how to do it.

Comment: Have you looked at the Javadoc for the JsonObject class and seen any methods that tell you how to access another object?

Comment: Note: success field is a boolean, not a String

Comment: just copy and paste my solution it will work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to parse JSON in same manual way you have to do like this to get token.

```
try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        if (jsonObject.getBoolean("success")== true) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "UserExists", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            JSONObject dataObj= jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
            String token= dataObj.getString("token");

            ////RETRIEVE "token" HERE
        } else {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User not registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Volley`, why not simply use the `JsonObjectRequest`:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, 
    url, 
    null, 
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            // parse the response   
            JSONObject data= response.getObject("data");
            String token = data.getString("token");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO: Handle error
        }
    }
);

MySingleton.getInstance(this).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
    Request.Method.GET, url, null, 
    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) { 
            JSONObject dataObj = response.getObject("data");
             String token = dataObj.getString("token");
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            // TODO: Handle error
        }
    }
);
```

Please use POJO for parsing. Otherwise you will take more time to do this kind of work.

Comment: But this is incompatible type. JSONObject dataObj = jsonObject.getString("data"); Error at this line

Comment: @user response.getObject("data"

Answer (score 0):

You can try like following.

```
public void parseData(String response) {
     try {
         JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
         if (jsonObject.getString("success").equals("true")){
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"UserExists",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

               ////RETRIEVE "token" HERE
               JSONObject dataObject = jsonObject.getObject("data");
               String token = dataObject.getString("token");
          }
          else {
              Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"User not registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
      }catch(JSONException e) {
         Log.e("YourTAG","exceptions "+e.toString());
    }
```

Hope it helps you.